# How to add more fonts in ckeditor in drupal

Tags: drupal, fonts, ckeditor

Can someone help me?how to add more fonts in ckeditor fonts dropdown in drupal?

Answer (score 0):

Wysiwyg fonts  module for drupal helped me,maybe will help someone also.Here is a link.thanks..
https://github.com/dale42/wysiwyg_fonts

Comment: wysiwyg_fonts is only for TinyMCE, rather than CKEditor.